# Grant Resource to user to create table

Tags: oracle, squirrel-sql

I am trying to give privileges to a db user, and want to allow the user to create tables. Checking on "RESOURCE" privilege, it contains the following:

```
SELECT privilege FROM dba_sys_privs WHERE grantee = 'RESOURCE';
```

Resource

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE TYPE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE INDEXTYPE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE SEQUENCE
```

As I noted that CREATE TABLE is included, I assumed it will be possible to grant RESOURCE to my user and the user will be able to create tables in his own schema.

```
GRANT RESOURCE TO User1;
```

On User1, I run the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE testable (
        sessionID varchar2(32 char) not null,
        attributeA varchar(10) ,
        attributeB varchar2(50)
    );
```

However I get this:

```
Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1031
```

If I manually grant "CREATE TABLE" to User1 instead, it works. Why is this so?

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO User1;
```

Comment: Hope that after giving resource grant to the user,  you have relogin with the user. Means disconnect and connect the user and try creating the table. Also, grant resource should be executed from sys user.

Comment: You are right, I need to reconnect after granting resource, but not for granting create table. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to **reconnect** with your user once it is given `resource` grant(from sys user) as your `current session` can not identify the newly given grant (resource).

Cheers!!

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue then accept it so that this question is marked as resolved.